# Update and create an entry in the same view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new in Django and I am developing a CRUD application for initiatives.
The 'add' and 'delete' actions are working well.
For the update action, instead of overwriting the initiative once the user confirmed, I would like to change the status of this initiative to 'DELETED' and add a new line for the modified initiative in my database.

Here is what I have so far for creating a new initiative, which is working well:

```
def init(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InitiativeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() :
            try :
                form.save()
                return redirect('/show')
            except :
                pass
    else:
        form = InitiativeForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is what I have for deleting an initiative. I don't want to delete the initiative but just want to switch the status to 'DELETED'. This also working well:

```
def destroy(request, id):  
    initiative = Initiative.objects.get(id=id)
    initiative.status_init = Status.objects.get(status = 'DELETED') 
    initiative.save(force_update=True)  
    return redirect('/show')
```

But for the updating action, I would like to keep the previous record and switch the status to 'DELETED' (as I do for deleting an initiative) and I would like to save the new record as a new line (as I do for creating a new initiative). Here is the current code I have:

```
def update(request, id):  

    initiative = Initiative.objects.get(id=id)
    form = InitiativeForm(instance = initiative)

    if form.is_valid():
        initiative.status_init = Status.objects.get(status = 'DELETED') 
        initiative.save(force_update = True)  
        form.save()
        return redirect('/show')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

But it's only adding a new line with the modified initiative. It doesn't switch the status of the current record to 'DELETED'.
Any idea why?
Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, but `form` and `initiative` might be pointing to the same thing. Use a debugger to look at that.

You could try something like this which (untested) should update status to DELETED, and create a new record. This may not work as intended, but it might put you in the right direction.

```
def update(request, id):  
    initiative = Initiative.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InitiativeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            initiative.status_init = Status.objects.get(status = 'DELETED') 
            initiative.save(update_fields=['status',])  
            # form.save()  # I believe this is now equivalent to initiative - play with your debugger to confirm
            # create a new object
            Initiative.objects.create(id=id, **request.POST)
            return redirect('/show')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input of AMG, I have tried the following code but it stills adding the new initiative but doesn't switch the status of the initial initiative as 'DELETED'

```
def update(request, id):  
    initiative = Initiative.objects.get(id=id)
    form = InitiativeForm(instance = initiative)
    if form.is_valid():
        initiative.status_init = Status.objects.get(status = 'DELETED') 
        initiative.save(update_fields=['status'])  
        Initiative.objects.create(id=id, **request.POST)
        return redirect('/show')
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form': form})
```